# Rspec test for when an I18n key is missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How do you simulate a missing I18n key in an Rspec test? I have a helper that looks to use a I18n key if its available. I don't know how to create the test case for when it is not available. Based on console testing I'm pretty sure the helper method is correct, but I don't know how to construct the test against that outcome (when all three possible title types are not set).

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

def available_page_title
  title = ""
  case
  when content_for?(:page_title)
    title = content_for(:page_title)
  when !@page_title.nil?
    title = @page_title
  when I18n.exists?('page_title.default')
    title = t('page_title.default')
  end
end
```

--

```
# config/locales/en.yml

en:
  page_title:
    delimiter: ' - '
    default: Default Page Title
    admin_namespace: 'Admin'


# spec/helpers/application_helper.rb
describe 'available_page_title' do
  it '(1) returns the the translation title if no other titles set' do
    allow(I18n).to receive(:t).with('page_title.default').and_return("Test Title from i18n")
    @page_title = nil
    expect(helper.available_page_title).to eq(t('page_title.default'))
  end

  it '(2) returns the the @page_title if it exists and no content_for exists' do
    allow(I18n).to receive(:t).with('page_title.default').and_return("Test Title from i18n")
    translation_title = t('page_title.default')
    @page_title = "Test Title from @page_title"
    expect(helper.available_page_title).to eq(@page_title)
  end

  it '(3) returns the the content_for title if it exists' do
    allow(I18n).to receive(:t).with('page_title.default').and_return("Test Title from i18n")
    translation_title = t('page_title.default')
    @page_title = "Test Title from @page_title"
    helper.content_for(:page_title, 'Test Title from content_for')
    expect(helper.available_page_title).to eq('Test Title from content_for')
  end

  it '(4) returns a blank string if no titles are found' do
    # Things I've tried...
    # I18n.backend.store_translations(:en, { page_title: { default: '' }})
    # I18n.backend.store_translations(:en)
    # I18n.backend.store_translations(:en, { nil })
    # I18n.backend.store_translations()
    # I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Simple.new
    allow(I18n).to receive(:t).with('page_title.default').and_return(nil)
    @page_title = nil
    expect(helper.available_page_title).to eq('')
  end
end
```

Here's the test results:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:130
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb"=>[130]}}

Randomized with seed 14478

ApplicationHelper
  available_page_title
    (3) returns the the content_for title if it exists
    (1) returns the the translation title if no other titles set
    (2) returns the the @page_title if it exists and no content_for exists
    (4) returns a blank string if no titles are found (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) ApplicationHelper available_page_title should (4) return a blank string if no titles are found
     Failure/Error: expect(helper.available_page_title).to eq('')

       expected: ""
            got: "Default Page Title"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:160:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.69197 seconds (files took 4.32 seconds to load)
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:152 # ApplicationHelper available_page_title should (4) return a blank string if no titles are found

Randomized with seed 14478
```

**Update 2017-05-31**

@gwcodes's answer helped a little but still didn't get the test set up properly.

```
allow(I18n).to receive(:translate).with('page_title.default').and_return(nil)
```

Using that line, the test is set up so that there actually is still a key `page_title.default`, but its value is nil. That's not useful.

What my helper method checks for is the existence of the key. Here's the pry output of the current test situation:

```
[5] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationHelper::AvailablePageTitle>)> I18n.translate('page_title.default')
=> nil
[6] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationHelper::AvailablePageTitle>)> I18n.exists?('page_title.default')
=> true
[7] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationHelper::AvailablePageTitle>)> I18n.t('page_title.default').empty?
=> false
```

So the question still remains. How do you set the test environment so that a check for the existence of an I18n key returns false?

Comment: I also just tried setting the I18n backed to nil as seen [Railscast #256](http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends): `I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new({})` and that seemed to get me closer but I got a `I18n::InvalidLocale: :en is not a valid locale` error and am as stuck as ever.

Comment: I also refactored a line that was bugging me: `when !@page_title.nil?` becomes simply `when @page_title` in the helper_method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking to use your first solution into a shared context.

```
# spec/support/i18n_stubs.rb

RSpec.shared_context 'i18n stubs' do
  def stub_i18n_value_with_nil(key)
    allow(I18n).to receive(:t).with(key).and_return(nil)
    allow(I18n).to receive(:exists?).with(key).and_return(false)
  end
end
```

Then add `require support/i18n_stubs` on your spec helper file. Inside wherever your spec file needs it, you can just simply put `include_context 'i18n stubs'` and call `stub_i18n_value_with_nil('some.i18n.key')` before doing assertions.

For example in spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe 'some_file_or_class' do
  include_context 'i18n stubs'

  describe 'available_page_title' do
    context 'when i18n key is not present' do
      before(:each) do
        stub_i18n_value_with_nil('some.i18n.key')
      end

      it 'returns blank string' do
        # do assertion here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @baskara. I haven't tried to move it to a shared context, but your solution worked: `allow(I18n).to receive(:exists?).with('page_title.default').and_return(false)` Like most good solutions, it seems simple and obvious in retrospect. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did come up with a solution by stubbing an I18n Backend for testing (although it does seem a little like the ball peen hammer approach).

I created spec/support/i18n_simple_stub.rb:

```
module I18n
  module Backend
    class SimpleStub
      def exists?(key, *args)
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then set the backend in that (previously failing) test. Here's the new test:

```
it '(4) returns a blank string if no titles are found' do
  # Sets exists? method to false
  I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::SimpleStub.new 
  @page_title = nil
  expect(helper.available_page_title).to eq('')
end
```

If anyone has a better method, I'd love to hear it and learn.

Comment: I think changing the behavior of the function unnecessarily entirely might have ramifications in other test suites. So, have you considered @baskara's answer? does it work?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I knew it felt like the hammer approach to fixing something. @baskara's answer did indeed work.